# Angular subscribe. Can't get to data

Tags: angular, typescript, api, service

**UPDATE**
How I managed to do it is below (scroll to my answer or here's the link): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55013081/1729405

I'm trying to build a APIService in Angular 7. I'm using subscribe to push to an array which I can't access through another service.

Here's the api service method:

```
  getResponse(url):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, '', {responseType: 'text'});
  }

  getAll() {
      this.getResponse(this.todayApiUrl).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.data.push(response);
        });

      return this.data;
  }
```

Here's how I'm trying to call it in the secondary service:

```
export class AdsHealthService {
  today = this.callResponseApiService.getAll();


  constructor(private callResponseApiService: CallResponseApiService) { }

  getHealthValue(interval, type) {
    let obj = this.today;
    console.log(obj);
  }
}
```

In the attached image is what I get when I `console.log()` the response. It looks like an array but when I try to access the first element, I get an `undefined` message. What am I doing wrong??
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the `http.post` is asynchronous, you can make it synchronous by making the `getResponse()` `async`, transforming the `Observable` to `Promise` by `.toPromise()` and adding `await` before the `http.post` since that the `getResponse()` will not return Observable but raw data so the `.subscribe()` is no more necessary.

```
  async getResponse(url) {
    return await this.http.post(url, '', {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
  }

  async getAll() {
    this.data = await this.getResponse('some url');
    return this.data
  }
  async some() {
    const data = await this.getAll();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting a promise back with the solution you provided. How would you get the value out of a promise?
async getAll() {
      let promise = this.http.post(this.todayApiUrl, '', {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
      promise.then(function(value) {
        return value;
      });
      this.today = await promise;
      console.log(this.today); // this returns a string value
      return this.today;
  }

In AdsHealthService class:
this.data = this.callResponseApiService.getAll();
    console.log(this.data); // this returns a promise object instead of a string

Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Thank you for pointing it out. Because `getAll()` is `async` you have to call it with await too.

Comment: When reference this.data outside of async function some(), I still get undefined. Is there a way to get the string value outside of the async function (because all async functions return a promise)?

Comment: What do you want to do with that data just display them in UI or some modification?

Comment: I'm hoping to modify the data that gets returned from the HTTP request.

Comment: I still get the same result. As you got with subscribe.

Comment: I was able to get it by chaining promises together. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Ok nice, could you please edit my answer? Or post here the solution?

Comment: You got it! Answer is below. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your service you would need the following:

```
  async getResponse(url) {
    return await this.http.post(url, '', {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
  }

  async getAll(url) {
    return await this.getResponse(url);
  }
```

In another service/component, you can retrieve the promise like below. To ensure that you're getting a promise back, you'd need to use a try catch block.

```
  async getToday() {
    try {
      let today = await this.yourServiceName.getAll(this.todayApiUrl);
      return today;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

then call:

```
let data = this.yourServiceName.getToday();
this.data.then((res) => {
// do stuff with 'res' here.
}
```

There isn't a way to save the value outside a then scope. To avoid hitting the API multiple times, I set up a cache service so that you can store/retrieve from cache when necessary. Here's the link to the article that I referenced for caching: https://hackernoon.com/angular-simple-in-memory-cache-service-on-the-ui-with-rxjs-77f167387e39

Here's what you can do:

```
  if (!this.cacheService.has('some key')) {
    let data = this.yourServiceName.init();
    this.cacheService.set('some key', data)
  } else {
    let cache = this.cacheService.get('data');
    // do stuff here.
  }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting data or data as null or undefined because your rest endpoint will return data in the future but your return statement is returned immediately.

Below are the ways you can solve this

- use `async` pipe in template and `.map` in the service
- get the data when ready in your component by using `map`

below are code

```
  // one method is fine to return data from rest endpoint
  getAll(url):Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post(url, '', {responseType: 'text'});
   }
```

In you component class

```
export class AdsHealthService {

  constructor(private callResponseApiService: CallResponseApiService) {
     this.callResponseApiService.getAll().subscribe( (today) => {
       let obj = today;
       console.log(obj);
     });
  }

 rawdata = this.callResponseApiService.getAll();


}
```

Incase you directly show the data in template you can do that using `async` pipe.

`<div>{{rawdata | async}}</div>`

Comment: I was able to get it using Promises instead. For some really odd reason, the Observable wouldn't return in a way I could get the data. No idea why. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

In your app-component:

```
public getDataFromService() {
  this._api.getData(this);
}


public setData(data: any){
 this.data=data;
}
```

In your service.ts:

```
public getData(obj: appComponentModel){
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => obj.setData(res));
}
```

its not exactly in the same format as your question but is easy one to understand by anyone.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack. Appreciate the answer. If I ever get back to a situation like this, I'll check out your solution. :) I haven't touched this since it's been launched.